# Passing an Array of Records to a C-routine in ADA

Tags: c, ada

I want to pass an Array of records to a C-routine from an ADA program.
The C code looks as follows:

dongo.h

```
typedef struct _RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER
{
    const char * name;
    const char * value; 
} RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER;

void  open(RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER const * connectionParams,  int n);
```

dongo.c:

```
#include "dongo.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void  open(RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER const * connectionParams, int n)
{
    int i;
    printf("Hello\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d : %s = %s\n", i,connectionParams[i].name,connectionParams[i].value);      
    }
}
```

The ADA-Code is:

```
with dongo_h; use dongo_h;
with Interfaces.C; use Interfaces.C;

with System;

procedure main is
   type RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER_PTR is access all RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER;

   type RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER_ARRAY      is array (Interfaces.C.int range <>) of RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER_PTR;
   pragma Convention (C, RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER_ARRAY);
   par :   RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER_ARRAY(1..2);
   begin
      par(1) := new RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER;
      par(2) := new RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER;
      par(1).name       := New_String("ABC");
      par(1).value      := New_String("123");   
      par(2).name       := New_String("ABC");
      par(2).value      := New_String("456");  
      open(par'Address,2);
end;
```

The Makefile for the Mingw64-Toolchain is:

```
main.exe : main.adb dongo.h dongo.c
    gcc -fdump-ada-spec  dongo.h
    gcc -c -m64 dongo.c
    gnatmake  -c main.adb 
    gnatbind -x main.ali  
    gnatlink -M -v  main.ali   -lmingw32  dongo.o  -o main.exe
```

The program gnerates weird randomized output, what indicates that the argument passing is not working at all. After unsuccessfuly looking in the internet for comprehensive examples I am posting this question here in the hope that someone could explain me how the parameter passing could be done correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks to the helpful hints from the forum members I can show my final solution :

main1.adb:

```
with dongo_h; use dongo_h;
with Interfaces.C; use Interfaces.C;
with Interfaces.C.Strings; use Interfaces.C.Strings;
with System;

procedure main1 is
    type RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER_ARRAY is array (Interfaces.C.int range <>) of RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER;
    pragma Convention (C, RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER_ARRAY);
    par :    RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER_ARRAY(1..2);

begin
    par(1).name     := New_String("ABC");
    par(1).value    := New_String("123");   
    par(2).name     := New_String("ABC");
    par(2).value    := New_String("456"); 
    open(par'address,2);
end;
```

Comment: The array on the C-side is an array-of-struct, but the array on the Ada-side looks like an array-of-pointer-to-structs (not sure, never used Ada).

Comment: Dirk is correct.  The C code is expecting an array where each array element is two "words" (two pointers, actually).  But each element in the Ada array is only one "word" (one pointer).  So they won't match up.  If you want more help, please post the Ada declaration of the type RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER, and any other user-defined types involved.  Also, is `New_String` the one in `Interfaces.C.Strings` or your own?

Comment: Yes thank you both. When changing Mehtod signature in the C program to: `void open(RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER const ** connectionParams, int n);` it works.

Answer (score 1):

The comments to your post were correct, you need to have an array of records and pass the pointer to that to the imported function.

```
with Interfaces.C.Strings; use Interfaces.C.Strings;
procedure Main is
  function NS renames New_String;
  type Record_Parameter is record
    Name  : Chars_Ptr;
    Value : Chars_Ptr;
  end record;
  type Array_Record_Parameter 
    is array (Int range <>) of Record_Parameter;
  type Access_Array_Record_Parameter
    is access all Array_Record_Parameter;
  pragma Convention(C, Access_Array_Record_Parameter);
  procedure Open_With(
    Parameters : in Access_Array_Record_Parameter;
    Count      : in Int);
  pragma Import(Stdcall, "open", Open_With);
  Parameters : aliased Array_Record_Parameter :=
    ((NS("ABC"), NS("123")), (NS("ABC"), NS("456"))); 
  begin
    Open_With(Parameters'access, Int(Parameters'length)); 
  end Main;
```

EDIT: 'Access should have been used instead of 'Unrestricted_Access and Parameters should have been 'aliased'

Comment: Wonderful answer. The code works indeed. In my environment I had to change the `with` -Statement to `pragma Import (C, Open_With, "open");`

Comment: Why are you using 'Unrestricted_Access?

Comment: Obviously the `unrestricted_access` seem to act as the `&`in C. Actually the code works also with all types and signatures changed to `Array_Record_Parameter` only. Then `Open_With(Parameters, int(Parameters'length))` works without this "cast".